# Angular Typescript - Filter objects from a list of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of objects. I have 3 filter parameters and Filter button on the screen. User can enter any one filter or multiple filter parameters. I have to search from the list and display data. Sample screen and input/output is as below. Also provided the code I have written so far. I can do this by writing a lot of combinations of `if`, `else if`. But I think there must be a better way.
[image]

```
Input                    Output
First Name: Br           2 rows, i.e. Brian Joseph Turner 

Input                    Output
First Name: Br
Middle Name: Fr          No rows    


Input                    Output
First Name: J            2 rows  i.e. Jonathan . . .   and James . . .
Middle Name: a
```

**student.component.ts**

```
public studentList: Student[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchAll();
}
  searchAll() {

    this.studentService.getAllStuidents()
      .subscribe((studentList: Student[]) => {
        this.studentList= studentList;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(studentList);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      },(error: any) => {
        
      });
  }

  search(): void {
    if(this.firstName.trim() == '' && 
        this.middleName.trim() == '' && 
        this.lastName.trim() == '') {

      this.newStudentList= this.studentList;

    } else {
      this.newStudentList.length = 0;
      this.studentList.forEach((s: Student) => {     
        if(s.firstName.indexOf(this.firstName) > -1) {   **// How to write the logic here**
          this.newStudentList.push(s);
        }
      })
    }
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.newStudentList);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

}
```

Comment: Instead of adding a student if they pass one of the filters, try starting with all the students, and applying each filter in order. See [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set all the filters at once with the following kind of loop:

```js
const filters: { field: keyof Student, value: string }[] = [
  {
    field: 'firstName',
    value: this.firstName,
  },
  {
    field: 'middleName',
    value: this.middleName,
  },
  {
    field: 'lastName',
    value: this.lastName,
  },
];
this.newStudentList = this.studentList;
for (let filter of filters) {
  if (filter.value) {
    this.newStudentList = this.newStudentList.filter((student) => student[filter.field].indexOf(filter.value) > -1);
  }
}
```

Here, `filters` is an array of objects, each of which represent one of the filters.

Having `filter.field` be of type `keyof Student` will prevent typos when setting `filters`.